# conditions without repeats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, conditional-statements

Hi i'm using this for getting data:

```
Topic.find(:all, :include => ...,
:conditions => @core ? ["cores_topics.id = ? AND visible = 1 AND (distance < ? OR cores.id IN (?))",@core.id, @user_location[3].to_i, @user_friends] : 
["visible = 1 AND (distance < ? OR cores.id IN (?))", @user_location[3].to_i, @user_friends], 
...
```

how can i rewrite the conditions shorter?

Comment: You could explain what you're trying to achieve with this code, so we can suggest a better way :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i rewrite the conditions
>   shorter?

User smaller variable names.

OK, really. Read the docs for [named_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#M002177). Your code is crying out for them.